# System Volume Information filling up; ways to alleviate?

Tags: windows, storage, vss, vssadmin

On all versions of Windows Server from 2012R2 onward, we are seeing System Volume Information folders, especially on server C: drives but also others, often filling up with hundreds of gigabytes of orphan shadows. We have been able to alleviate this by using secondary RAID volumes or partitions for page files (keeping C: page file at 1024G only), but would like to have more approaches at any level, including changes to server specification. Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> filling up with hundreds of gigabytes of orphan shadows

This is not how it should work by any means. Who or what (3rd party maybe) creates those shadow copies? Check if the "appear" when VSS is disabled and triple check for any 3rd party security- and/or av- products.